# Insert mysql error when parsing a webpage

Tags: php, mysql

Hi when ever I want to insert a comment into my database, I sanitize the data by using Mysql Escape String function this however inserts the following verbatim in field. I print the comment and it works fine and show me the text however when ever I sanitize it, it literally inserts the following into my db

```
  mysql_real_escape_string(Comment)
```

This is my insert statement, The Id inserts correctly however the comment doesn't it just inserts the "mysql_real_escape_string(Comment)" into the field. what can be wrong?

```
 foreach($html->find("div[class=comment]") as $content){
  $comment = $content->plaintext;
  $username = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
   $querytwo = "insert into Tchild(Tid,Tcomment)values('$id','$username')";

   $resulttwo = $db -> Execute($querytwo);
  }
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated, use mysqli_real_escape_string instead

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` here or something else?

Comment: @tadman no I'm not using Mysqli anywhere else

Comment: I'm just wondering what MySQL layer you're using, since you're calling `$db->Execute` which is not familiar.

Comment: @JOELEE the $id is assigned to an interger and it inserts fine, but the comment(string) doesnt insert when I use mysql_real_escape

Comment: I can see what escaping function you're using, but that only works with `mysql_query`, and you shouldn't be using that in the first place. What does `$db->Execute` refer to?

Comment: @tadman Im using myphpadmin, it works fine to run queries

Comment: @karthikr The mysqli version still doesnt work

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it does, but my question is *specifically* what database layer you're using here.

Comment: you or some one else asked an identical question yesterday.

Comment: @Dagon that was my brother, I think he never got an answer so I had to ask a new one

Comment: @tadman Im using a MYSQL server

Comment: we prefer you edit the original or engage in the comments, rather than just re asking - thanks.

Comment: You need to find out where `$db->Execute` goes, because that's where your problem lies. You're not [escaping your data](http://bobby-tables.com/php) correctly if you're getting raw function calls in your database. I know you're using MySQL server. You're avoiding the question of what database layer you're using. Is it a framework? Your own creation? Something you downloaded? It's impossible to answer this without knowing.

Comment: @tadman here is my db connection <?
require "../adodb5/adodb.inc.php";
function adodbConnect()
{
  $host='******';
  $user='*****';
  $database='*****';
  $pwd = '****';
  // make sure we access the active data objects library
  $db = NewADOConnection('mysql');//create a new connection Active Data Objects
  $db->Connect($host, $user, $pwd, $database); // connect
  return $db;
}
?>

Comment: That's much better. Thanks.

Comment: echo out the query. are you missing a space before values ?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading [the documentation](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) correctly, you should make the call like this:

```
$db->Execute("insert into Tchild(Tid,Tcomment)values(?, ?)", array($id, $username));
```

That will account for proper escaping. Having unescaped values in your query string is dangerous and should be avoided whenever possible. As your database layer has support for SQL placeholders like `?` you should make full use of those any time you're placing data in your query.

A call to `mysql_real_escape_string` will not work unless you're using `mysql_query`. It needs a connection to a MySQL database to function properly.

Comment: How exactly does the array work? in the values you put ?,? then you put the array with the values on the right. what Im I suppose to put in the ?,? and why is the array there? thank you

Comment: yes, i use ADODB and use this.  the array is your map to the placeholders ("?") in the parameterized sql statement.

Comment: +1 After thinking about it a bit, I like your answer better than mine.

Comment: So I replaced it with this example and it actually just now puts "comment" in each field. The field is mediumtext and latin1_swedish colation

Comment: You should double-check what your variables are just before the query is executed. `$username` might be `"comment"` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ADODB, what you want is probably `$db->qstr()`. For example:

```
$username = $db->qstr($comment, get_magic_quotes_gpc());
```

See this page for more information: http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm

Comment: If ADOdb has placeholders, this is completely redundant.

Comment: @tadman sorry about that, I slipped up while copy-and-pasting. If you take a look at the ADODB documentation I linked to, you'll see why that call to get_magic_quotes_gpc() is there.

Comment: are we to assume php plug-in for IIS

Comment: Yeah, saw that after you fixed it. Still, having "magic quotes" on is a very bad idea and should be turned off rather than accounted for inside your code.

Comment: FYI, you don't HAVE to use placeholders with ADODB.